# React, Typescript - Print fetched data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sharepoint, web-parts, tsx

I am trying to print data from fetched JSON but somehow i am unable to do it.

```
interface IFetched {
  fetchedData: any;
  error: any;
}

export default class Testing100 extends React.Component<
  ITesting100Props,
  IFetched,
  {}
> {
  constructor(props: ITesting100Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      fetchedData: [],
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.randomuser.me/")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            fetchedData: result,
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            error,
          });
        }
      );
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<ITesting100Props> {
    console.log(this.state.fetchedData.results);
    return (
      <div>
        <a>
          {this.state.fetchedData.map(function (fetchedDataX) {
            return fetchedDataX.results[0].name.first;
          })}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

With console log i am able to print data. But when i change console log from `console.log(this.state.fetchedData.results);` to `console.log(this.state.fetchedData.results[0]);` i get nothing. And even that console log is called twice as you can see in console output i dont know why.
[image]

But my goal is to print the first name of person into `<a>` element and I just don't know how. Hope somebody can help me with this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is the output when you try `console.log(this.state.fetchedData.results[0]);`?

Comment: `[1595589428411][OtherGlobalError.window.onerro] EventName:TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined, ResultCode: undefined` its pretty weird i think.

Comment: Yeah so that's because `results` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the state of the app before the fetch occurs - the `fetchedData` array is empty. Then when you fetch, you are converting it into an object, with a `results` field that is an array.

Your code needs to be able to handle both of these states. Don't try to use or log a field of something that you haven't first verified actually exists, or it will crash.

---

First step is to clean it up so you directly just update the array in the state -
Your map is not working because fetchedData has an inner `results` field - try `this.setState({fetchedData: result.results});`, and then `console.log(this.state.fetchedData)`.

---

Also you might want to add some guards to the top of your `render` so that things don't crash when the fetchedData is empty or errored:

```
if (this.state.fetchedData === []) return <p>"Nothing Loaded"</p>;
if (this.state.error !== null) return <p>{this.state.error.message}</p>;
```

---

As for the double output to the console, that is because the `render` method get run first when the component is mounted, and you see the output where the `fetchedData` is empty, and then `componentDidMount` runs (which fetches the data and updates the state) and then React re-renders with the new state, causing the second console log.

Your console log that tries to access the `.result[0]` fails because it doesn't exist for this first pre-fetch state. Check (with an if) it is there before logging, or log the whole state obj.

Comment: Wow its trully working thanks for explanation very much i was playing with this like for sooooo long. Thanks again.